# SAS Studio mega-variable to variables

Tags: sas, sas-studio

i need your help with SAS Studio, i got this variable with 200 hundred products and each of them has this ID and this one begins with 001,002,003....200 how can I split this mega-varible to variables for each product

Answer (score 3):

Use an array to store the 200 products, iterate over the variable `bigvar` and `scan()` off each product, storing into the corresponding array element.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array prd{*} prod1-prod200 ;
  nprod = countw(bigvar,',') ;
  do i = 1 to nprod ;
    prd{i} = scan(bigvar,i,',') ;
  end ;
  drop i nprod ;
run ;
```

Comment: and what if  i got this delimiter "\xx" in each product ???? it doesn´t matter???